# Who's the composer?

Tags: riddle, pattern, music

> One December,
>   You are in the casino, but about a quarter of the cards are missing.
>   You see a blue bird fly past the window.
>   A person walks by you and you think like #TheDress.

I know this is definitely not a good poem, but each line represents a song from that composer. Find who the composer is.

Hint 1:
All 4 are pop songs. The last line represents a song that she (yes, it's a she) sang but is not very famous.

Edit 2: 
For the previous edit, I accidentally put "changed a word", it's more like "added Hint 1".

Hint 3:
All sentences are hidden by word play. This isn't a cryptogram. The phrase which hides the songs are in bold in the spoiler:

First line:

> One ***December***,

Second line:

> You are in the casino, but about ***a quarter of the cards*** are missing.

Third line:

> You see a **blue bird** fly past the window.

Fourth line:

> A person walks by you and you think like ***#TheDress***.

Comment: Christina Perri turns out to be a song-writer as well and she does write her own songs. So both are applicable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer seems to be

> Christina Perri

The four songs are:

> 1. Something About December https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kWJrUGjZwr4
>  2. ??? Jar Of Hearts ???
>  3. Bluebird https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vO5NLUOD8v8
>  4. Black and Blue https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zo3vX0EwAdA and
>  http://www.wired.com/2015/02/science-one-agrees-color-dress/

Comment: Yep. That's it. I thought that I could use the "Hearts" in "Jar of Hearts" as a suit of cards being "kept away".

Answer (score 3):

Taylor Swift wrote "Back to December", talked about #thedress recently, wrote "Welcome to New York" (New York has tall buildings). I don't know about a quarter of the cards, though.

Comment: Sorry but er... no since all the lines are actually pop songs. But nice try!

Answer (score 2):

My answer:

> Demi Lovato

One December,

> "Remember December"

a quarter of the cards are missing.

> "Give Your Heart a Break" amongst many other songs with 'hearts'

You look out of the windows and see the tall buildings outside.

> "Skyscraper"

A person walks by you and you think like #TheDress.

> Not sure on this one, maybe "Neon Lights" (color of the dress based on lighting?)

Comment: When I read your answer, I realised something... one of the songs i set as a hint was not sung by her... sorry! I'll edit it quickly!